# tail recursive vs iterative algorithms

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion, iteration

I couldn't find articles describing why tail recursive functions should be preferred over iterative algorithms.

I'm not asking why tail recursive is better than simple recursive which I think is clearly explained everywhere.

So why

```
sum(n) = {
    def sumImpl(n, acc) = if(n <= 0) acc  else sumImpl(n - 1 , n + accumulator)
    sumImpl(n, 0)
}
```

is preferable to

```
sum = 0;
while(n--) sum += n
```

Comment: for its self-evident correctness. and in fact, your second snippet is indeed incorrect - it is equivalent to `sum1(n-1)`, where I write `sum1` for your first function which you also named `sum`. the hand-rolled iteration is so very often much more prone to such errors than its equivalent syntactically recursive formulation. specifically, `while(n--)` decrements `n` _before_ it is added to the accumulator, so the very first `n` value is missed.

Answer (score 9):

Recursion makes a program more readable, but it gives poor performance. Iterative procedures give good performance but are not that readable and may require a local variable to store an intermediate value (mutability). Using tail recursion you will get the best of both worlds and no "sum" variable is needed (immutability). This is very useful in calculating large number sums or factorials, because you will never get a stackoverflow exception as you just forward the result to the next recursive function call.

In a parallel environment immutability is very important. Try to edit your code and pass very large numbers to the function to see the difference.

Further reading [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RecursionVsLoop)

Comment: In the previous case the functional aproach is not more readable. Still should I choose that version?

Comment: Your example is trivial. In this case iterative is obvious choice. To see difference between Iterative, recursive, tail recursive calls try this one. http://ideone.com/i0md7

Comment: So you're saying that the tail recursive one could be more efficient than iterative (6times more for fibonacci)?
fibonacciIt  - Position: 10000 Time: 137275432 ns
fibonacciTail- Position: 10000 Time:  20357861 ns
I will check myself :D. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recursion consumes more memory (overhead of stack frames) and more cpu cycles (overhead of creating & destroying stack frames). It however makes code more readable. Iterations makes code less readable but frees up more memory and cpu, so it may be needed for constrained environments e.g. IOT decvices, phones etc. See here for a good description [https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~shidi/cs61a/wiki/Iteration_vs._recursion#:~:text=Iteration%20and%20recursion%20are%20both%20ways%20to%20achieve%20repetition%20in%20programs.&text=All%20iterative%20functions%20can%20be,is%20defined%20as%20tail%20recursion](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Eshidi/cs61a/wiki/Iteration_vs._recursion#:%7E:text=Iteration%20and%20recursion%20are%20both%20ways%20to%20achieve%20repetition%20in%20programs.&text=All%20iterative%20functions%20can%20be,is%20defined%20as%20tail%20recursion).

Comment: While recursion consumes more memory, tail recursion doesn't and can be translated directly to iterative without consuming stack frames. Sometimes iterative is easier to understand than tail recursion and the question is why still prefer tail recursion? It is just a purist approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in your choice of programming paradigm.
The declarative style (used in functional programming think Scala) versus
imperative style (think iteration in java).

In the functional paradigm we want to avoid side-effects. So we want to deal with expression i.e. code that returns a value. Using recursive functions is one way to do that.

In Java we might change the state of an object inside a loop this would be regarded as a side-effect.

The bottom line, neither approach is necessarily bad. However, we should avoid using imperative constructs such as loops in functional languages use recursion instead.